Slow databricks query when filtering by one column and sorting by another
We have huge table which stores information about blockchain blocks, of our particular interest is block number and its timestamp. Suppose we need to map timestamp to block number, to solve the task "give me the highest block before or at given timestamp". This task translates into SQL:
SELECT max(blockNumber) FROM blocks WHERE timestamp<=myvalue
However, on a large blockchain (173 million blocks and growing), this query takes 5 minutes. I understand that we are doing something wrong, but is there a way to improve things? I have read about Z-order, will it help here?

I love what I am seeing... applcation of databricks in cryptocurrency.
The slow performance of your query is likely due to inefficient data layout and lack of proper indexing for your filtering and sorting columns (timestamp and blockNumber).
Z-Ordering is highly effective for optimizing queries that filter on a specific column (timestamp in your case). Databricks will physically sort the data files in your Delta table based on the specified column, reducing the amount of data scanned during queries.
step 1: Convert your table to a Delta table if it isn't already. I guess you know how to do it, and I dont put codes here
step 2: Apply Z-Ordering: This clusters the data physically, improving the efficiency of range-based queries like WHERE timestamp <= myvalue.
OPTIMIZE blocks ZORDER BY (timestamp);

step 3: now try the query one more time
SELECT max(blockNumber) FROM blocks WHERE timestamp <= myvalue;

more solutions if you intrested in exploring are : Use Delta Caching, Partition the Table by timestamp

Thank you! We already use Delta Tables. Problem is not in finding timestamp, but in sorting by blockNumber. I have invented a solution which improved speed a lot. The biggest gap between the blocks is less than 50K blocks, so instead of saying: timestamp <= myvalue, I say: timestamp between myvalue - 50000 and myvalue. This scans a lot less records and completes a lot faster.
